# C# - Replace text mid-string and keep the rest of the string, duplicate lines

Tags: c#, string, text, replace, duplicates

I have two .txt documents and I would like to search in one of them for a keys from the secoond file. If the keys are found, I want to replace the match with the text that follows the key in the second file. Also, I would like to add a "T" or a "B" depending on the number in the file.

Here is an example of a first file:

```
   1       0010    SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT, TEXT
   .2      0020    SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT, TEXT, TEXT
   1       0020A   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT
   .1      2000    SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT
   ..3     9123A   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT
   ...     ...     ...                 ...
```

Here is an example of a second file:

```
  0010    ABCD EFG
  0020    C01
  0020A   C02, C3, C004, C9901, C938, C12
  2000    R123, R13, D34 
  9123A   SOMETEXT
  ...     ...
```

From these two files, I would like to use the "keys" from the second file (at the start of every new line). So in this example the keys would be: 0010, 0020, 0020A, 2000, 9123A.  After I have the keys I want to search the first text document in the second column to see if there is a match.  If there is a match (in this case they all match) I would like to replace the text in the first document and create a new document with the updated text. Also, if there are multiple values after the keys in the second file, I would like to copy the lines down.  Look below to see what I mean.

The new document would look like this:

```
   1       ABCD EFG   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOMETEXT, TEXT
   .2      C01        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT, TEXT, TEXT
   1       C02        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             //--------------------
   1       C3         SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             // Copied the lines
   1       C004       SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             // down if there are
   1       C9901      SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             // multiple values in
   1       C938       SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             // document 2.
   1       C12        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOMETEXT,TEXT              //--------------------
   .1      R123       SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT       //--------------
   .1      R13        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT       // COPIED ALSO
   .1      D34        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT       //--------------
   ..3     SOMETEXT   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT
   ...     ...     ...                 ...
```

Also, if the key(s) end with an "A" I would like to add a "T" to the end of the string above. If the key(s) do not end with an "A" I would like to add a "B" to the end of the string above.

Example of a few lines:

```
   .1      R123       SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT         B       //key was 2000
   .1      R13        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT         B       //key was 2000
   .1      D34        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT         B       //key was 2000
   ..3     SOMETEXT   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT                    T       //key was 9123A
```

---

---

**QUESTION(S):**

- How would I search one file for keys from a second file?

  - Once located, how do I replace the item in the first text with an item in the second text?
- After I replace the file, must I re-concatenate the string?
- After each line is correct, is there a 'best' way to add a "T" or "B" at the end of each line (this depends on the key having an "A" or not)?
- Any other recommendations to go about this?

---

Here is some code I have been trying to work with.. however I cannot get it how I want and the code is not working how I expected it to.:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;

namespace BOM_Formatter
{
  public partial class bomForm : Form
  {
    // Create OpenFileDialogs to request paths and file names to open.
    OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    OpenFileDialog openRefs = new OpenFileDialog();

    // Create a SaveFileDialog to request a path and file name to save.
    SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();

    string filePath = "C:\\Users\\FileText.txt";
    string refsPath = "C:\\Users\\RefsText.txt";

    public bomForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //*********************************************************
    //******************* OPEN FILE BUTTON ********************
    //*********************************************************
    private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the OpenFileDialog to specify the .txt extension.
        openFile.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
        openFile.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt";
        openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

        try
        {
            // Open the contents of the file into the originalTextRichTextBox.
            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && openFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                originalTextRichTextBox.LoadFile(openFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            // Throws a FileNotFoundException otherwise.
            else
                throw new FileNotFoundException();

            // Calls to format the opened file.
            openFileFormatHelper();

            formattedTextRichTextBox.SaveFile(filePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }

        // Catches an exception if the file was not opened.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was not a specified file path.", "Path Not Found Error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    //*********************************************************
    //******************** OPEN REFS BUTTON *******************
    //*********************************************************
    private void openRefsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the OpenFileDialog to specify the .txt extension.
        openRefs.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
        openRefs.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt";
        openRefs.RestoreDirectory = true;

        try
        {
            // Open the contents of the file into the originalTextRichTextBox.
            if (openRefs.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && openRefs.FileName.Length > 0)
                refsTextRichTextBox.LoadFile(openRefs.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            // Throws a FileNotFoundException otherwise.
            else
                throw new FileNotFoundException();

            // Calls to format the opened refs file.
            openRefsFormatHelper();

            formattedRefsTextRichTextBox.SaveFile(refsPath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }

        // Catches an exception if the file was not opened.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was not a specified file path.", "Path Not Found Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    //*********************************************************
    //******************* SAVE FILE BUTTON ********************
    //*********************************************************
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the SaveFileDialog to specify the .txt extension for the file.
        saveFile.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
        saveFile.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt";
        saveFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

        try
        {
            // Save the contents of the formattedTextRichTextBox into the file.
            if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && saveFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                finalTextRichTextBox.SaveFile(saveFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            // Throws a FileNotFoundException otherwise.
            else
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }

        // Catches an exception if the file was not saved.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was not a specified file path.", "Path Not Found Error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    //*********************************************************
    //******************* CLEAR FILE BUTTON *******************
    //*********************************************************
    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Resets the text in all of the boxes.
            originalTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
            formattedTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
            refsTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
            formattedRefsTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
            finalTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
        }

        // Catches an exception if the either text box could not be cleared.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not clear the text.", "Clearing Text Box Error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    //*********************************************************
    //******************* FORMAT FILE BUTTON ******************
    //*********************************************************
    private void formatButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           //var list = new List<string>();
            openFileFormatHelper();
            openRefsFormatHelper();
           // formatAllHelper();

            finalFormatHelper();
        }

        // Catches an exception if the file was not opened.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not format text.", "Text Formatting Error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    private void finalFormatHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            string[] openFileFinal = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            string[] openRefsFinal = File.ReadAllLines(refsPath);

            var result = new List<string>();
            string theOutput;
           // StringBuilder finalOutput = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var fileLines in openFileFinal)
            {
                //Match numberStartMatch = Regex.Match(fileLines, @"^[\d]+");//[\s+[\d\w]+]*");
                var fileParts = fileLines.Split(' ');

                foreach (var refLines in openRefsFinal)
                {
                    var refsParts = refLines.Split(' ');
                    theOutput = fileParts.ToString();

                    if (fileParts[1].Equals(refsParts[0]))
                    {
                        theOutput = fileParts[0] + "\t" + fileParts[1].Replace(fileParts[1], refsParts[1]) 
                            + "\t" + fileParts[2] + "\t" + fileParts[3] + "\t" + fileParts[4];
                        result.Add(string.Join(" ", theOutput));
                    }
                    else
                        result.Add(theOutput);
                }
               // finalTextRichTextBox.AppendText(result.ToString());
                // Otherwise keep the line how it is.
            }
            foreach (var line in result)
            {
                finalTextRichTextBox.AppendText(line + "\n");
            }
        }

        // Catches an exception if the file could not be formatted.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem formatting the 'Final File'.", "Final File Format Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }


    //*********************************************************
    //******************* OPEN FILE HELPER ********************
    //*********************************************************
    private void openFileFormatHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            // Resets the formattedTextRichTextBox so multiple files aren't loaded on top of eachother.
            formattedTextRichTextBox.ResetText();

            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName))
            {
                // Uses regular expressions to find a line that has, digit(s), space(s), digit(s) + letter(s),
                // space(s), digit(s), space(s), any character (up to 25 times).
                Match theMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"^[\.*\d]+\s+[\d\w]+\s+[\d\-\w*]+\s+.{25}");

                if (theMatch.Success)
                {
                    // Stores the matched value in string output.
                    string output = theMatch.Value;

                    // Replaces tabs and extra space with only 1 space delimiter
                    output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\s+", " ");

                    // Sets the formattedTextRichTextBox to the string output.
                    formattedTextRichTextBox.AppendText(output);
                    formattedTextRichTextBox.AppendText("\n");
                }
            }
        }

        // Catches an exception if the file was not opened.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem formatting the 'Open File'.", "Open File Format Error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        // Creates a final string of the formatted rich text box.
        //string openFileFinal = formattedTextRichTextBox.Text.ToString();
    }

    //*********************************************************
    //******************* OPEN REFS HELPER ********************
    //*********************************************************
    private void openRefsFormatHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            formattedRefsTextRichTextBox.ResetText();
            // Reads the lines in the file to format.
            var reader = File.OpenText(openRefs.FileName);

            // Creates a list for the lines to be stored in.
            var list = new List<string>();

            // Adds each line in the file to the list.
            while (true)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null) 
                    break;
                list.Add(line);
            }

            // Handles all of the requirements for the reference text.
            list = fourDigitRequirement(list);
            list = concatRequirement(list);
            list = startsWithBRequirement(list);
            list = elementIsBRequirement(list);
            list = removeTRequirement(list);

            // Prints the formatted refs to the richtextbox.
            foreach (var line in list)
                formattedRefsTextRichTextBox.AppendText(line + "\n");

            // Creates a final string of the formatted refs rich text box.
          //string refsFileFinal = formattedRefsTextRichTextBox.Text.ToString();
        }

        // Catches an exception if the file could not be formatted.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem formatting the 'Refs File'.", "Refs File Format Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    //*********************************************************
    //****************** FORMAT ALL HELPER ********************
    //*********************************************************
   /* private void formatAllHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            finalTextRichTextBox.ResetText();

            // Reads the lines in the file to format.
            var fileReader = File.OpenText(formattedTextRichTextBox.Text);
            var refsReader = File.OpenText(formattedRefsTextRichTextBox.Text);

            // Creates a list for the lines to be stored in.
            var list = new List<string>();
            var list2 = new List<string>();

            // Adds each line in the file to the list.
            while (true)
            {
                var line = fileReader.ReadLine();
                var line2 = refsReader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                if (line2 == null)
                    break;

                list.Add(line);
                list2.Add(line2);
            }

            list = finalTextRequirement(list, list2);

            // Prints the formatted refs to the richtextbox.
            foreach (var line in list)
                finalTextRichTextBox.AppendText(line + "\n");
        }

        // Catches an exception if the file could not be formatted.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem formatting the 'Final Text' file.", "Final File Format Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }

    public List<string> finalTextRequirement(List<string> list, List<string> list2)
    {
        // Creates variables of the text in the two rich text boxes.
        var openFileFinal = File.ReadAllLines(formattedTextRichTextBox.Text);
        var openRefsFinal = File.ReadAllLines(formattedRefsTextRichTextBox.Text);
        StringBuilder finalOutput = new StringBuilder();
        var result = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            finalTextRichTextBox.ResetText();

            // Splits the text
            var openFileFinalLines = openFileFinal.Select(f => f.Split(' ')).ToDictionary(g => g[1], h => h);
            var openRefsFinalLines = openRefsFinal.Select(f => f.Split(' ')).ToDictionary(g => g[0], h => h[1].Split(','));

            foreach (var line in openFileFinalLines)
            {
                if (openRefsFinalLines.ContainsKey(line.Key))
                    finalOutput.Append(Combine(line.Value, openRefsFinalLines[line.Key]));

                else
                    finalOutput.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", line.Value));
            }
        }

        // Catches an exception if the final output could not be created.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem creating the final document.", "Final Text Formatting Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        finalTextRichTextBox.Text = finalOutput.ToString();
        return result;
        /*
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();
        var openFileFinal = File.ReadAllLines(formattedTextRichTextBox.Text);

        foreach (var line in openFileFinalLines)
        {
            if (openRefsFinalLines.ContainsKey(line.Key))
                finalOutput.Append(Combine(line.Value, openRefsFinalLines[line.Key]));

            else
                finalOutput.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", line.Value));
        }
    }

    string Combine(string[] openFileFinalLines, string[] openRefsFinalLines)
    {
        StringBuilder aBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var theString in openRefsFinalLines)
        {
            aBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", openFileFinalLines[0], theString, openFileFinalLines[2],
                openFileFinalLines[3], openFileFinalLines[1].EndsWith("A") ? "T" : "B"));
        }

        return aBuilder.ToString();
    }*/

    //*************************************************************
    //***************** ELEMENT IS B REQUIREMENT ******************
    //*************************************************************
    // This handles the requirement of the second element in the list being a "B".
    static List<string> elementIsBRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');

            // Checks if the second 'part' array is "B"
            if (parts[1].Equals("B"))
            {
                // If it is "B", replace with "A" and add to the new list "result"
                parts[0] += "A";
                parts[1] = string.Empty;

                result.Add(string.Join(" ", parts));
            }

            // Otherwise keep the line how it is.
            else
                result.Add(line);
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    //*************************************************************
    //***************** STARTS WITH B REQUIREMENT *****************
    //*************************************************************
    // This handles the requirement of the element starting with a "B".
    static List<string> startsWithBRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();
        var i = 0;

        // Checks if the line begins with "B"
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');

            // Checks if the first 'part' array is "B"
            if (parts[0].Equals("B"))
            {
                // If it is "B", copy the previous line down and add "A" where "B" was at
                // and add to the new list "result"
                parts[0] = string.Empty;
                result.Add(list[i - 1].Split(' ')[0] + "A" + string.Join(" ", parts));
            }

            // Otherwise keep the line how it is.
            else
                result.Add(line);

            i++;
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    //*************************************************************
    //****************** CONCAT LIST REQUIREMENT ******************
    //*************************************************************
    // This handles the requirement of concatting the list.
    static List<string> concatRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');
            int test;

            // Concats everything together
            if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out test) || parts[0].Equals("B"))
                result.Add(line);

            // Otherwise result - 1
            else
                result[result.Count - 1] += line;
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    //*************************************************************
    //***************** REMOVE THE T REQUIREMENT ******************
    //*************************************************************
    // This handles the requirement of removing the "T".
    static List<string> removeTRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');

            // Checks if the second 'part' array is "T", if it is, remove "T"
            if (parts[1].Equals("T"))
                parts[1] = string.Empty;

            // Add the new string to the result.
            result.Add(string.Join(" ", parts).Replace("  ", " "));
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }

    //*************************************************************
    //****************** FOUR DIGITS REQUIREMENT ******************
    //*************************************************************
    // This handles the requirement of the digits being a certain length.
    static List<string> fourDigitRequirement(List<string> list)
    {
        // Creates a new list to return with new format.
        var result = new List<string>();

        // Checks each line in the list.
        foreach (var line in list)
        {
            // Splits each line into 'parts'
            var parts = line.Split(' ');
            int test;

            // Checks if the array[0] (digits) is the proper length.
            if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out test))
            {
                // If it is not a length of 4 digits, add "O" to the front until it is.
                parts[0] = parts[0].PadLeft(4, '0');

                // Add the new string to the result list.
                result.Add(string.Join(" ", parts));
            }

            // Otherwise keep the line how it is.
            else
                result.Add(line);
        }

        // Returns the new list so it can be formatted further.
        return result;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Right now I have to save both text boxes to a .txt file before I can 'upload' them into the final format button to completely format and merge the files.  Is there anyway to not have to save the files as a hardcopy but rather upload them from both the formattedTextRichTextBox and the formattedRefsRichTextBox to be processes for more formatting?

Comment: Are the columns tab-delimited? or is it spaces?

Comment: tabs for the first file, spaces for the second

Comment: However, I can add: output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", " "); to make it so they are both in spaces.

Comment: Actually, I think it would be easier to convert to tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read in both files (maybe using File.ReadAllLines()). This would give you an array with all the lines in your files. From there, I would use LINQ Select method to project the lines as key value pairs (or something like that), maybe convert ToDictionary(). Then do all the fancy joining and logic in memory and write it back out to a new file. Code forthcoming (maybe)

EDIT: I think this generates the output you're looking for.

```
string FileMerger()
{
    var file1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\....\File1.txt");
    var file2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\....\File2.txt");

    var file1Lines = file1.Select(f => f.Split('\t')).ToDictionary(f => f[1], f => f);
    var file2Lines = file2.Select(f => f.Split('\t')).ToDictionary(f => f[0], f => f[1].Split(','));

    StringBuilder newOutput = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var line in file1Lines) 
    {
        if(file2Lines.ContainsKey(line.Key)) 
        {
            newOutput.Append(Combine(line.Value, file2Lines[line.Key]));
        }
        else 
        {
            newOutput.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", line.Value));
        }
    }

    return newOutput.ToString();
}

string Combine(string[] file1Line, string[] file2Line)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var str in file2Line)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", file1Line[0], str, file1Line[2], file1Line[3], file1Line[1].EndsWith("A") ? "T" : "B"));
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: On the lines where you set file1Lines & file2Lines, what does everything  after the "Select" mean? Also, I typed this into my code and MS Visual Studio 2010 does not recognize the f.Split from the "Select(f => f.Split...);" text

Comment: The Select statement takes every element in the array and applies some transformation to it (a "projection"). So the file1Lines equals every line from file1 split on tabs, then converted to a dictionary, where the Key of the dictionary is the 2nd element of the array (index 1), and the value is the whole line (as an array split on tabs).....as for the error you're getting for f.Split(..), could you paste the error you're getting? it's an instance method on the string class.

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks for the explanation! It just says: 'char' does not contain a defintion for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using irective or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I figured out the error.. I missed the "File.ReadAllLines".. oops

Comment: However, now MSVS2010 does not recognize the multiple f's and the Split(',') in the ".ToDictionary"

Comment: :-/ I execute the code before pasting it...not sure what's missing. can you paste those 2 lines as you have them in your code?

Comment: var openFileFinalLines = openFilefinal.Select(f => f.Split(('\t')).ToDictionary(f => f[1], f => f);
var openRefsFinalLines = openRefsFinal.Select(f => f.Split(('\t')).ToDictionary(f => f[0], f => f[1].Split(',')));

Comment: However, if I change it to this: var openFileFinalLines = openFilefinal.Select(f => f.Split(('\t')).ToDictionary(**g** => **g** [1], **h** => **h**); var openRefsFinalLines = openRefsFinal.Select(f => f.Split(('\t')).ToDictionary(**g** => **g** [0], **h** => **h** [1].Split(','))); I only get a "red line" under "h => h[1].Split(',')" instead of the others as well

Comment: And the error says "Cannot convert the lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<char>' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: I changed it a bit after researching some more.. would this work? : var openRefsFinalLines = openRefsFinal.Select(f => f.Split(('\t')).ToDictionary(g => g[0], h => **h.Split(',')** )); : there is no **[1]** now and the error is gone.. but I do have some errors in the foreach loops –

Comment: I'm sorry you're having trouble. I think part of the trouble with this line is the parentheses. It should be: 
    `var openRefsFinalLines = openRefsFinal.Select(f => f.Split('\t')).ToDictionary(g => g[0], h => h[1].Split(','));`
Notice you had double parentheses around the first call to Split and double parentheses at the end of the line.

Comment: I am posting all of my code above... (soon) I am stuck on this last part and can't figure it out to save my life! :(

Comment: The two open buttons (openButton & openRefsButton) open a nonformatted file and formats them into the format that is posted above.

Comment: Sorry I actually posted old code from a different an older copy.... I am now reposting the newest code!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library to read the files which will read the files into objects. Then you can use Linq to merge the two results and produce the new file.